# How do I access the "most official" repository for architecture specific GCC runtime source files&tests?

Tags: gcc, avr-gcc

Here&there I find the likes of *mulqi3.S* & *divmodhi4.S*.

Is there a reference anywhere on gnu.org on how to **browse** current official revisions of such architecture specific source code? What is the relation to LLVM?
If not, can you point me to a current resource? Download, if browsing is not supported.

What do "they" use for regression testing architecture specific routines;
is there something I could easily use myself?

Comment: (I hope a reference on (gcc?.)gnu.org stays useful after changes such as migrating from SVN to GitHub.)

Comment: (Even the 4.6 libgcc.S looks better.)

Comment: Library source code as of 2024/03: [github libgcc/config/avr](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=tree;f=libgcc/config/avr;hb=HEAD)